# Converting from feed_dict to queues results in increasing loss

Tags: tensorflow

I have a working tensorflow model that I am trying to convert to using queues. It may not be the best function but it works.

The data comes in as a list(dict()) called 'rows' from a processing pipeline outside of TF in the form format [{'y1': 1,  'y2': 0, 'y3':1, 'y4':0, 'x1':...'x1182': 0}] (SPECIAL_FIELD_CHAR is 'y', meaning it's calculated from the 'xN' data). The features_outputs() just returns the xs and the ys as ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4'] and ['x1', ..., 'x1182']. The idea is that the xs determine the ys. There are 4 independent ys that are calculated per row of xs.

```
def train_rows(initial_weights, weights_filename, rows):
    (features, outputs ) = features_outputs(rows[0].keys())

    x_true = [ [float(row[feature]) for feature in features] for row in rows]
    try:
        y_true = [ [float(row[output]) for output in outputs] for row in rows ]
    except Exception as e:
        print [row[output] for output in outputs], e

    w_true = np.random.rand(len(features), 1) # init weights
    b_true = np.random.rand(1) # init bias

    x_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, len(features)], "x_in")
    if initial_weights is None:
        w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((len(features), len(outputs))), name="w")
        b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[len(outputs)]), name="b")
    else:
        w = tf.Variable(weights['w'], name="w")
        b = tf.Variable(weights['b'], name="b")

    h = tf.add(tf.matmul(x_in, w), b, name="h")
    y_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, len(outputs)], "y_in")
    loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.subtract(y_in, h)), name="loss")
    #train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss_op)
    train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.3).minimize(loss_op)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        last_error = 1.7976931348623157e+308
        this_error = 1.7976931348623157e+307
        diff = 1
        iteration = initial_weights['iteration'] if initial_weights is not None and 'iteration' in initial_weights else 0
        while diff > 0:
            iteration += 1
            last_error = this_error
            for step in range(1000):
                sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={
                  x_in: x_true,
                  y_in: y_true
                })

            w_computed = sess.run(w)
            b_computed = sess.run(b)

            pred = tf.add(tf.matmul(x_in, w), b)

            results = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x_in: x_true})
            error = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, results)
            this_error = float(error.eval())
            (diff, locs) = compare(y_true, results)
            if locs < 50:
                print "iteration:", iteration, "error:",this_error, "diff:", diff, "locs:", locs
```

This produces a model that converges. However with the queue based version it does not, and error increases rapidly:

```
def multithreaded_train_rows(initial_weights, weights_filename, rows):
    (features, outputs ) = features_outputs(rows[0].keys())

    x_true = np.array([ [float(row[feature]) for feature in features] for row in rows])
    y_true = np.array([ [float(row[output]) for output in outputs] for row in rows ])


    #queue
    q = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=len(rows), dtypes=tf.float32)
    #enq_op = q.enqueue_many(x_true)
    enq_op = q.enqueue_many(np.array( [ [float(row[f]) for f in sorted(row.keys())] for row in rows]  ))
    qr = tf.train.QueueRunner(q, [enq_op] * 1)
    tf.train.add_queue_runner(qr)

    keys = sorted(row.keys())
    x_indices = np.array([[i] for i in range(len(keys)) if not keys[i].startswith(SPECIAL_FIELD_CHAR)])
    y_indices = np.array([[i] for i in range(len(keys)) if     keys[i].startswith(SPECIAL_FIELD_CHAR)])

    input = q.dequeue()

    x_in = tf.transpose(tf.gather(input, x_indices))
    y_in = tf.gather(input, y_indices)

    if initial_weights is None:
        print 'Creating weights', len(x_indices), len(y_indices)
        w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((len(x_indices), len(y_indices))), name="w")
        b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[len(y_indices)]), name="b")
    else:
        print 'Using supplied weights', len(weights['w']), len(weights['w'][0])
        w = tf.Variable(weights['w'], name="w")
        b = tf.Variable(weights['b'], name="b")

    y = tf.add(tf.matmul(x_in, w), b, name="y")

    loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(y_in, y), name="loss")
    train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.3).minimize(loss_op)

    print 'Starting session'
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
        last_error = 1.7976931348623157e+308
        this_error = 1.7976931348623157e+307
        diff = 1
        iteration = initial_weights['iteration'] if initial_weights is not None and 'iteration' in initial_weights else 0
        while diff > 0:
            iteration += 1
            last_error = this_error
            for step in range(100):
                sess.run([train_op, loss_op])

            w_computed = sess.run(w)
            b_computed = sess.run(b)

            pred = tf.add(tf.matmul(x_in, w), b)

            results = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x_in: x_true})
            error = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, results)
            this_error = float(error.eval())

            (diff, locs) = compare(y_true, results)
            if locs < 50:
                print "iteration:", iteration, "error:",this_error, "diff:", diff, "locs:", locs

        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```

They are meant to be the same, but I've had to change a few things:
1. Add a tf.transpose() to the x_in for the matmul()
2. Queue the entire row of xs and ys, then pull apart using tf.gather().

I've searched a lot for examples that match mine, and I can find no documentation on how to restart a queue and continue the training from the beginning. It'll seemly train forever(not sure why, who is replenishing the queue?) It'll also never stop.

But most of all I have no idea why given the exact same data, the first converges and the second does not?

Answer (score 0):

- None of the gather marshalling is needed. Queue only the inputs (x_true), then
- evaluate y against y_true, not y_in

  ```
  loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_true), name="loss")
  ```